# NWJS compiling binary for different OS and different arch

Tags: node.js, v8, nwjs

I need help in compiling binary files from MacOS to Windows32 & Windows64 bit. In [documentation](https://nwjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/For%20Users/Advanced/Protect%20JavaScript%20Source%20Code/) it is written that we need to compile binary according to platform but actual options/parameters are not provided in documentation for it

Got the parameters from `nwjc --help` section, tried with following but nothing works:

```
nwjc --target-os win32 --target-arch ia32 nwapp/main.js nwapp/main.bin
nwjc --target-os win32 --target-arch x86_64 nwapp/main.js nwapp/main.bin
nwjc --target-os win32 --target-arch x64 nwapp/main.js nwapp/main.bin
```

By default, the binary compiled on MacOS is running on 64 bit windows without any target parameters.
Can you give me the parameters and possible values for compiling for Windows32 & Windows 64 from MacOS?

Answer (score 0):

I have got the answer from [nwjs gitter group](https://gitter.im/nwjs/nw.js). The answer is:

> If you want to compile JS files to v8 binary files for a target
>   platform, let's suppose Windows 32 bit, then you need to compile them
>   on the target platform only. You cannot compile binaries for Windows
>   32 from a different OS (in my case I was trying with MacOS)